# Can an SVG drawing be converted so that there are no overlapping elements?

Tags: svg

I'm working on a project that plots SVG graphics. So far I have it working when no elements overlap, but I run into trouble when the elements are superimposed. As an example, let's say I have an SVG with a black square 100x100 and inside of it (and on top of it) I have a red circle with a diameter of 50. When the svg is rendered, the center of the square is invisible, since the circle is on top of it and is rendered on top. But if I were to draw it, I'd need to draw the square MINUS the circle, and then the circle itself. I have found some libraries that allow me to subtract one path from the other, but that seems to be very computationally expensive, so I'm wondering if there's a better approach to this problem. In essence, I need to take an arbitrary SVG and produce another SVG that's visually identical to the original one but where no elements overlap one another, so the Z order is irrelevant. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow .. But I *think* you're talking about [Clipping and Masking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking) ?

Comment: What you describe is in the domain of grafical editors like Inkscape or Illustrator. How to achieve your goals would be more appropriate to ask at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Zak - not really, I'd like to convert paths, not mask or clip them.

Comment: @ccprog you're not wrong! Illustrator seems to have the functionality that I need - Pathfinder / trim does the trick. However, I'd like to apply it programmatically, rather than a manual one-off operation

Comment: The _border_ of your ``<circle>`` is **inside** the ``<rect>`` It is not overlapping the _border_ of the rect. So it requires converting vector _"shape"_ information to pixel notation, then checking if **pixel** x,y coordinates are the same.  Illustrator, and Browsers when clipping/masking, do something like this with highly optimized C++ code. Doing this with JS will take some serious CPU cycles. Maybe go the WASM route.